# Как объединить C и java?

Tags: java, android, c

Нужно написать мобильное приложение на android, но основная часть кода (так сказать, ядро) должна быть написана на Си. Можно ли как-то объединить эти два языка?
Какие есть библиотеки для этого? 
Если у кого было такое - поделитесь)
Нужно для курсача.

Comment: Это возможно. Гуглите ```Android NDK```.

Comment: я посоветую не пользоваться Андроид студией, которая умеет делать это из коробки, а сделать всё руками (собрать .so через ndk-build и потом уже добавить их в Java код).

Answer (score 3):

Да, это возможно. Для сишной части надо использовать [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html), Java часть где и обычный SDK.

NDK это по сути [сишный компилятор GNU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) слегка подрихтованный под Android и обогащенный специфическими либами.

Связка Java-C работает через [механизм JNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (Java Native Interface)

Простые примеры вызова из Java Android к сишным функциям [можно посмотреть здесь](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni)

Стандартный паттерн Java-C для Android следующий:

1. UI весь пишется под Java
2. Вычислительно тяжелые вещи на NDK

Необходимо учитывать, что Android работает на нескольких вычислительных платформах/архитектурах, соответственно, чтобы он работал везде сишная часть должна генерировать несколько библиотек. На текущий момент имеется 7 поддерживаемых NDK архитектур:

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86_64

[Подробнее здесь](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)

P.S. Отдельно отмечу, что писать под NDK занятие тяжелое и не очень благодарное. Особенно отладка кода - это жесть. Зато результат великолепен.